# SQL: Por qué el campo de tipo decimal es truncado?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Tengo unas sentencias en *SQL* (*MySQL*) que crean un esquema llamado *tienda* y añade a este tres entidades, *producto*, *cliente* y *proveedor*, con sus correspondientes relaciones. El problema está en la tabla *producto*, donde el campo `precioUnitario`, de tipo `decimal` es truncado.

Creación de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `tienda`.`producto`(
    codigo          int         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre          varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    precioUnitario  decimal     DEFAULT 1.80,
    Proveedor_FK    varchar(10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (codigo),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Suministra FOREIGN KEY FK_Suministra(Proveedor_FK)
    REFERENCES `tienda`.`proveedor`(NIE)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Introducción de datos en la tabla:

```
INSERT INTO `tienda`.`producto` (nombre,precioUnitario)
    VALUES  ('Secador de pelo',15.60),
            ('Toalla',1.80),
            ('Peine',2),
            ('Kit Higiene',6.50),
            ('Alfombrilla',2.30);
```

**¿Cómo puedo evitar que estas cantidades en `precioUnitario` sean truncadas?**

Comment: Sospecho que tu declaración de campo necesita un tamaño, en el `CREATE TABLE`: Ejemplo `precioUnitario  decimal (4,2) DEFAULT 1.80` Para más info mira esto: http://elclubdelautodidacta.es/wp/2012/05/mysql-datos-numericos-de-coma-fija/ Explico: 4, 2 significa que el número mayor de cifras que admitirá ese campo es 4, de las cuales 2 son decimales. Ese campo aceptará sólo precios menores o iguales a 99.99

Comment: Pues si, no sabía que el tipo de dato decimal permite aplicar un formato! Gracias por tu comentario

Comment: En realidad no es un **formato** sino una declaración de tamaño de campo. El formato se lo das a la salida, en el `SELECT`. Ahora te mostraré un ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conviene asignar un tamaño a los [campos decimales](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html), como se hace con cualquier otro campo.

Sólo que en MySQL la asignación de tamaño en campos decimales se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
salary DECIMAL(7,2)
```

lo cual significa que el campo `salary`tendrá 7 dígitos, de los cuales 2 serán decimales.

No está mal para un salario ¿no?, podremos ganar 99,999.99 como máximo.

**Nota:**
En esa declaración no se está dando formato al campo, se está solamente asignando un tamaño. El formato, como recomiendan las buenas prácticas, debe darse en la salida, es decir, en el `SELECT` o bien en el programa con el que estemos trabajando (PHP u otro).

Para formato podemos usar la función [`FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format) combinada si queremos con los [servicios locales](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html) que ofrece MySQL.

Ejemplo:

[Demo en SQL Fiddle](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla
    (
    codigo int,
    nombre varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    precioUnitario  decimal  (5,2)   DEFAULT 1.80
    )
;

INSERT INTO tabla (codigo, nombre, precioUnitario)
    VALUES  (1,'Secador de pelo',15.60),
            (2,'Toalla',1.80),
            (3,'Peine',2),
            (4,'Kit Higiene',6.50),
            (5,'Alfombrilla',2.30);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  nombre,
  CONCAT("$",FORMAT(precioUnitario, 2, 'en_US')) AS moneda_US,
  CONCAT("€",FORMAT(precioUnitario, 2, 'es_ES')) AS moneda_ES,
  FORMAT(precioUnitario, 2, 'es_ES') AS no_monedaES
FROM
  tabla
```

**[Results](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format)**:

```
|          nombre | moneda_US | moneda_ES | no_monedaES |
|-----------------|-----------|-----------|-------------|
| Secador de pelo |    $15.60 |    €15,60 |       15,60 |
|          Toalla |     $1.80 |     €1,80 |        1,80 |
|           Peine |     $2.00 |     €2,00 |        2,00 |
|     Kit Higiene |     $6.50 |     €6,50 |        6,50 |
|     Alfombrilla |     $2.30 |     €2,30 |        2,30 |
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, entiendo ahora la diferencia entre dar un tamaño y un formato (no suelo medir mucho las palabras o suelo considerar como semejantes aquellas que no lo son, mea culpa!) y como aplicar ambos. Pero hay una instrucción que no logro entender, y es `FORMAT(precioUnitario, 2, 'es_ES') AS no_monedaES`

Comment: Significa: _formatea el campo `precioUnitario` con 2 cifras decimales y utiliza el formato local `es_ES`, es decir, el correspondiente a España y dale a esa columna el nombre de nomonedaES en la salida_  Según el formato local que des te hará la separación de miles con punto, con coma u otro. En uno de los enlaces podrás ver los diferentes formatos locales de MySQL por países.

Comment: Entonces la única diferencia con respecto a las anteriores es la ausencia de la concatenación del símbolo de la moneda. ¿Podría decir que el motivo de existencia de esa instrucción está en que así podremos trabajar con esos datos sin problemas, al no tener el símbolo de la moneda?

Comment: @JD0001 Es correcto. En la BD se guardan siempre los datos planos y el formato se le da a la salida, de ese modo tus datos quedan libres de toda camisa de fuerza. En este ejemplo tú puedes presentar los números con cualquier símbolo delante, puedes hacer conversiones según el tipo de cambio, a cualquier moneda, etc. porque el dato está solo en la BD. Si tuviera el símbolo dentro de la BD sería más complicado, sería como ponerle una camisa de fuerza a tus datos... He editado la respuesta con los ejemplos de sqlfiddle funcionando. Saludos.